# Eating food without Kufi ( head cap) is Makrooh?

Tags: fiqh, clothing, makruh

Assalamu Alaikum my Brothers in Islam,

A local imam told me this morning that

1) eating food without wearing the kufi/ topi / head cap is Makrooh.

2) If keffiyeh falls down while praying Salah, it is Makrooh.

Are these claims supported by any Saheeh evidence? 
If yes please give me references from the hadith!

Comment: Once I've been asked to lead the Friday prayer in a Turkish mosque and actually while praying the sunnah the Fez or what ever the head cover which was given to me is told felt down. Of course the prayer is valid as covering the head is not necessary for the prayer it is something recommended in general, but for example during hajj wearing a head cover is not even allowed for men.

Comment: Alright. But is there a sahih hadith that specifies that eating food without a cap is makrooh?

Answer (score 1):

Bismi Allah Ar Rahman Ar Rahim.

In the name of God, the Most Gracious, the Most Merciful.

All Perfect Praise be to Almighty God,

and prayers and peace be upon the Messenger of Allah and his family and companions,

Having said that,

Peace be upon those who follow guidance

there is nothing wrong with eating or praying without headcover, and those saying so should be afraid from Allah that they are making up things that weren't mentioned in Quran or by Our Messenger Prayers and Peace from Allah upon him

We ask Allah to always teach us and show us the right path to guidance

and God knows best.